# C# оптимизация многократного подключения к MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Здравствуйте, знакомлюсь тут с C# и MySQL и, пока игрался, решил задачу, но сомневаюсь в подходе. Прошу не акцентироваться на практической полезности задачи: она для примера.

**Используется:** VS 2015, Windows Forms + MySql.Data.MySqlClient

**Задача:** приложение имеет таймер (timer1), который каждые 3 секунды добавляет новую запись в табличку БД MySQL на сервере.

Реализовать достаточно легко, почитав любую короткую статью-введение в работу с MySQL в C#. Добавляем таймер и код в событие его тика:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=...;user=...;database=...;password=...;");
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO...;", conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Это будет работать. Но насколько рационально? Каждый тик создается и открывается то же соединение (*conn*), создается та же команда (*command*), выполняется и соединение закрывается. Во-первых, можно и нужно ли вынести куда-то вне тика создание *conn* и *command*, чтобы тик просто использовал их однажды созданные экземпляры? И во-вторых, можно и нужно ли также вынести открытие соединения и просто всегда держать приложение с открытым соединением?

И того событие тика можно облегчить до `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Если это все же разумно, то куда все повыносить, чтобы это было доступно для timer1_Tick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При работе с базой данных MySQL подключения(`MySQLConnection`) берутся из [пула подключений](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) - эта механизм управления подключениями к БД. Он по-умолчанию включен. 
Когда вы создаете новый объект `MySQLConnection` и открываете его, то соединение будет создано из пула соединений вместо создания нового родного соединения к БД. 
Поэтому не важно, будете вы постоянно создавать объект `MySQLConnection` или где-то откроете один раз и будете держать, разницы нет. Лично я часто использую соединения с коротким временем жизни - соединение взял из пула, вернул обратно.

 
НО, выдержка из ссылки, которую скинул

> To work as designed, it is best to let the connection pooling system manage  all connections. Do not create a globally accessible instance of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it. This interferes with the way the pooling works and can lead to unpredictable results or even exceptions.
>
> One approach that simplifies things is to avoid manually creating a
> MySqlConnection object. Instead use the overloaded methods that take a
> connection string as an argument. Using this approach, Connector/Net
> will automatically create, open, close and destroy connections, using
> the connection pooling system for best performance.

Поэтому, ***не создавайте глобальный MySQLConnection.***. Доверьтесь пулу подключений.

Главное на что еще нужно обратить внимание - это правило использования одного соединения в одном потоке.
Если у вас [таймер из пространства имен System.Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), то там таймер вызывается не всегда из одного потока, поэтому создание нового объекта подключения будет оправдано.